# error TypeError: Object of type Undefined is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

Estoy teniendo un serio problema al momento de desarrollar una web...
se supone q tengo un archivo .py llamado all.py para realizar las acciones de navegacion entre mis paginas, exportar datos a la base de datos access y importar datos de la misma, los dos funcionan de maravilla y no tengo problemas con exportar y la navegacion de mis paginas... el problema viene al momento de importar, necesito que mi pagina "pendientes.html" muestre en forma de lista las discrepancias que estan en la base de datos, y eso no eh podido lograrlo. mi codigo es el siguiente.
all.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import pyodbc
from flask import jsonify
import json

# apartir de aqui es exportar.py

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates')  # Indica la carpeta de plantillas

conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=\\10.7.219.194\share-lnv\Discrepancias\discrepancias.accdb;'
)

def insertar_en_acces(datos):
    try:
        print("Insertando datos:", datos)
        connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        sql = '''
            INSERT INTO DiscrepanciasTemporal 
            (fecha, planta, complemento, orden, usuario, qtyrequerida, ruta, sku, qtydiscrepancia, tipodiscrepancia, linea, lot, horareporte)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        '''

        cursor.execute(sql, (
            datos['fecha'], datos['planta'], datos['complemento'], datos['orden'],
            datos['usuario'], datos['qtyrequerida'], datos['ruta'], datos['sku'],
            datos['qtydiscrepancia'], datos['tipodiscrepancia'], datos['linea'],
            datos['lot'], datos['horareporte']
        ))

        cursor.commit()
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("Datos insertados correctamente.")
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error al insertar datos:", e)

@app.route('/enviar', methods=['POST'])
def enviar_formulario():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("Recibiendo solicitud POST")
        datos = {
            'fecha': request.form['fecha'],
            'planta': request.form['planta'],
            'complemento': request.form['complemento'],
            'orden': request.form['orden'],
            'usuario': request.form['usuario'],
            'qtyrequerida': int(request.form.get('qtyRequerida', 0)),  # Manejo de campos numéricos
            'ruta': request.form['ruta'],
            'sku': request.form['sku'],
            'qtydiscrepancia': int(request.form.get('qtyDiscrepancia', 0)),  # Manejo de campos numéricos
            'tipodiscrepancia': request.form['tipoDiscrepancia'],
            'linea': request.form['linea'],
            'lot': request.form['lot'],
            'horareporte': request.form['horaReporte']
        }
        print("Datos del formulario:", datos)
        
        try:
            # Convertir los valores a enteros usando una comprobación
            datos['qtyrequerida'] = int(request.form.get('qtyRequerida', 0))
            datos['qtydiscrepancia'] = int(request.form.get('qtyDiscrepancia', 0))
            insertar_en_acces(datos)
            print("Datos insertados en la base de datos")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error al insertar datos en la base de datos:", e)

    return render_template('reporte.html')

#apartir de aqui es app.py

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('menu.html')

@app.route('/reporte', methods=['GET'])
def reporte():
    return render_template('reporte.html')

@app.route('/pendientes', methods=['GET'])
def pendientes():
    return render_template('pendientes.html')

@app.route('/redirigir-menu', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def redirigir_menu():
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

# apartir de aqui es bd.py

# Configuración de conexión a la base de datos
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=\\10.7.219.194\share-lnv\Discrepancias\discrepancias.accdb;'
)

# Función para obtener los datos de la base de datos
conn_str = (
    r'DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};'
    r'DBQ=\\10.7.219.194\share-lnv\Discrepancias\discrepancias.accdb;'
)

# Función para obtener los datos de la base de datos
def obtener_discrepancias():
    connection = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    query = "SELECT * FROM DiscrepanciasTemporal"
    cursor.execute(query)
    discrepancias = cursor.fetchall()

    cursor.close()
    connection.close()

    return discrepancias

@app.route('/pendientes', methods=['GET'])
def mostrar_pendientes():
    discrepancias = obtener_discrepancias()

    discrepancias_list = []
    for d in discrepancias:
        discrepancias_list.append({
            'discrepanciaID': d[0],
            'fecha': d[1],
            'planta': d[2],
            'complemento': d[3],
            'orden': d[4],
            'usuario': d[5],
            'qtyrequerida': d[6],
            'ruta': d[7],
            'sku': d[8],
            'qtydiscrepancia': d[9],
            'tipodiscrepancia': d[10],
            'linea': d[11],
            'lot': d[12],
            'horareporte': d[13]
        })

    return render_template('pendientes.html', discrepancias_list=discrepancias_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

y el codigo de mi html es
pendientes.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Discrepancias Pendientes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles-pendientes.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="background-container"></div>
    <div class="titulo-container">
        <h1 class="titulo">Discrepancias Pendientes</h1>
    </div>
    <form class="menu-link boton-menu">
        <button type="button" id="regresar">Menú Principal</button>
    </form>
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="discrepancia-menu">
            <ul>
                {% for discrepancia in discrepancias %}
                    <li class="discrepancia-item">
                        <div class="discrepancia-summary" data-id="{{ loop.index }}">
                            <h2>{{ discrepancia.discrepanciaID }}</h2>
                            <p>{{ discrepancia.tipodiscrepancia }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="discrepancia-details">
            <div class="details-content" id="details-content">
                <!-- ... Resto de los detalles ... -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2023 Ceva Logistics</p>
    </footer>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("regresar").addEventListener("click", function() {
            window.location.href = "/redirigir-menu";
        });

        const detailsContainer = document.getElementById('details-content');
        const discrepancias = {{ discrepancias_list|tojson|safe }};
        console.log("Discrepancias en JS:", discrepancias);

        const summaryItems = document.querySelectorAll('.discrepancia-summary');
        summaryItems.forEach(item => {
            item.addEventListener('click', () => {
                const itemId = item.getAttribute('data-id');
                const details = obtenerDetallesDiscrepancia(itemId);
                detailsContainer.innerHTML = details;
            });
        });

        function obtenerDetallesDiscrepancia(id) {
            if (id >= 1 && id <= discrepancias.length) {
                const discrepancia = discrepancias[id - 1];
                return `
                    <h2>Detalles de la discrepancia #${id}</h2>
                    <p>Fecha: ${discrepancia.fecha}</p>
                    <p>Planta: ${discrepancia.planta}</p>
                    <p>Complemento: ${discrepancia.complemento}</p>
                    <p>Orden: ${discrepancia.orden}</p>
                    <p>Usuario: ${discrepancia.usuario}</p>
                    <p>Qty Requerida: ${discrepancia.qtyrequerida}</p>
                    <p>Ruta: ${discrepancia.ruta}</p>
                    <p>SKU: ${discrepancia.sku}</p>
                    <p>Qty Discrepancia: ${discrepancia.qtydiscrepancia}</p>
                    <p>Tipo de Discrepancia: ${discrepancia.tipodiscrepancia}</p>
                    <p>Línea: ${discrepancia.linea}</p>
                    <p>Lot #: ${discrepancia.lot}</p>
                    <p>Hora de Reporte: ${discrepancia.horareporte}</p>
                `;
            } else {
                return "Discrepancia no encontrada.";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

si mi codigo esta mal estructurado, confuso o enredado, quiero decir que no tengo mucho conocimiento en programacion y he estado usando una IA para generar el codigo, pero llego a un punto donde ya no me dio resultados, necesito su ayuda, si necesitan mas info con gusto les doy mas informacion.

Comment: Hola Madison, fijate que cuando haces `def pendientes():
    return render_template('pendientes.html')`, te esta faltando enviar `discrepancias_list` y por eso falla.

Comment: eh intentado lo q me dijiste pero ahora me sale 
NameError
NameError: name 'discrepancias_list' is not defined
:(

Comment: Proba enviarlo así: `render_template('pendientes.html', discrepancias_list=[])`